# On the existence of a direct summand containing a fixed subgroup

Tags: gr.group-theory, abelian-groups, modules, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group, and $g_1, \ldots, g_n \in G$ such that the cyclic groups that they generate are in direct sum $\langle g_1 \rangle \oplus \cdots \oplus \langle g_n \rangle$. Is it always possible to find elements $h_1, \ldots, h_n \in G$ and integers $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ such that the following three facts hold

1. $g_i = a_i \cdot h_i$, for all $1 \leq i \leq n$,
2. the cyclic subgroups generated by the $h_i$ are in direct sum, $H:=\langle h_1 \rangle \oplus \cdots \oplus \langle h_n \rangle$.
3. $H$ is a direct summand of $G$?

(I asked this question on math.stackexchange, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199928/smallest-pure-subgroup-containing-a-fixed-subgroup)

Comment: Do you really mean that the $g_i$'s generate a cyclic group $C$? if so, why can't you take all of the $h_i$ to be the same element, a generator of the largest cyclic group containing $C$. My first thought is that this solution would satisfy (1), (2) and (3)... But I could be wrong.

Comment: No, I have edited my question. "The cyclic groupS that they generate" insted of "The cyclic group that they generate"

Comment: It should be obvious. Your $H$ is the pure subgroup generated by $g_i$-s, and in finite groups, pure subgroups should be the same as direct summands. 

Comment: @Bugs Bunny Can you give a reference for the "pure subgroup generated by"? Also, how do you find the generators $h_i$ each dividing $g_i$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_subgroup

Comment: Generate a subgroup $A$, then add all roots. This is the pure subgroup generated by $g_i$-s. Sorry, do not know references, it is all common sense.

Comment: I have problems with condition 3).  Either a sum for G is specified and H is supposed to be an appropriate subsum (in which case pick g's and h's to be diagonal to this sum to get the answer no), or else H is part of some direct sum for G in which case why not take H plus G/H.  Perhaps I have forgotten some group theory that makes condition 3 nontrivial?  Gerhard "Maybe Could Be The Answer" Paseman, 2012.09.21

Comment: @Bugs Bunny: I beg your pardon? $S=\langle (1,1)\rangle$ is a pure subgroup of $\mathbf{Z}_4\times\mathbf{Z}_2$; even though $2(1,0)\in S$, we do not have $(1,0)\in S$. "Pure subgroup generated by" would necessarily refer to "the smallest pure subgroup that contains the subgroup/set", but there need not be such a thing. For example, $S=\langle (2,0)\rangle$ in $\mathbf{Z}_4\times\mathbf{Z}_2$ is contained in both $\mathbf{Z}_4\times\{1\}$, which is pure, and in $\langle (1,1)\rangle$, which is pure; the intersection of these two pure subgroups is not pure, though.

Comment: @Bugs Bunny (that should be $\mathbf{Z}_4\times\{0\}$, not $\{1\}$, of couse... too much working multiplicatively). The link you provide has no reference to "pure subgroup generated by" a set. 

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong...

Comment: @Bugs Bunny: I think you may have gotten a bit tangled between this and the notion of "isolator": if $A$ is a subgroup of the abelian group $G$, then the isolator of $A$ is the set of all $g\in G$ such that $ng\in A$ for some $n$. This is not useful at all in torsion groups (you just get $G$); and in groups with torsion you always get the entire torsion subgroup in the isolator, but in torsionfree groups it's a useful construct. 

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am not convinced that this is true, because the pure subgroup generated by the $g_i$ might
not have the stipulated form as a direct sum of the $h_i$.

Let $G = {\mathbb Z}/16{\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z}/4{\mathbb Z}$, $n=1$, and $g_1=(4,2)$.
What could $h_1$ be?

We can prove that there is no such $h_1$ as follows. For any $g \in G$ of order 16, we have $8g = (8,0)$. Since $(8,0) \in \langle h_1 \rangle$, $\langle h_1 \rangle$ cannot be a direct summand of $G$ of order 4. So $\langle h_1 \rangle$ would have to be a direct summand of order 16. But then $4h_1 = (4,0)$ or $(12,0)$ and so $g_1 \not\in \langle h_1 \rangle$.

Comment: I think you mean $8g = (8,0)$...


Comment: Thanks but there is something I am missing. Why do you not start with $g_1=(2,1)$?

Comment: Anyway I am still not convinced about the pure subgroup generated by the $g_i$. What is it? You generate a subgroup with the $g_i$. Then you take the roots. Then? Is this a subgroup at all? Or do you have to still take the subgroup generated and continue?

Comment: @calc: A pure subgroup $S$ of $G$ is a subgroup such that $nG\cap S=nS$ for all $n$. You may not need to take roots; for example, in $G=\mathbf{Z}_4\times\mathbf{Z}_2$, $S=\langle (1,1)\rangle$ is pure: $2G\cap S = \{(0,0),(2,0)\} = 2S$, and that's the only one you need to worry about. Even though $2(1,0)\in S$, you do not need $(1,0)$ in $S$ for $S$ to be pure, you just need $2(1,0)$ to be twice *something* in $S$. 


Comment: @Calc: But if you have a subgroup $S$ of $G$, and you let $H=\{g\in G\mid ng\in S, ng\neq 0\}$ (which I suspect is what you mean; otherwise, in a torsion group, adding "all roots" would mean adding the entire thing), then $H$ need not be a subgroup; e.g., with $G$ and $S$ as above, $(1,0)\in H$ (since $2(1,0)=(2,0)\in S$ is nonzero), and $(1,1)\in H$ (since it is in $S$), but $(1,1)-(0,1)\notin H$. 

Comment: @Arturo: Yes, thanks, I did mean $8g=(8,0)$. I've corrected it.

Comment: @calc: Yes, $g_1=(2,1)$ would also work. In fact that would work in the direct sum of cyclic groups of order 8 and 2.

Comment: @Arturo. Thank you very much. Bugs Bunny mentioned the "pure subgroup generated" and everyone (including me) seemed to be convinced for a while that it existed. Even now the beginning of Derek's answer keeps track of this

Comment: @Derek. Thanks a lot, this was very detailed and helpful.

Comment: Actually, the simplest example is just $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ with element $(2,1)$, it seems to me.

Comment: @calc: No, $\langle (2,1) \rangle$ is a direct summand of ${\mathbb Z}_4 \oplus {\mathbb Z}_2$ with complement $\langle (1,0) \rangle$.

Comment: Sorry, I take it back.

Answer (score 1):

This old question just surfaced on MO for some reason, so I thought I'd add a comment to put Derek Holt's *excellent* answer in a wider context. Given a prime $p$, the problem of classifying pairs consisting of a finite abelian $p$-group of exponent $p^n$ together with a subgroup, up to isomorphism of pairs, is known to be of wild representation type for $n$ at least seven. See for example the paper of Ringel and Schmidmeier, "Submodule categories of wild representation type" (JPAA 2006). If what you're asking were true, it would imply a classification for such pairs. But more generally, trying to *tame* such pairs is destined to failure.